# C# SSL/TLS Client/Server App Remote Certificate Chain Errors

Tags: c#, powershell, ssl, ssl-certificate

Alright so I know that this question has been asked many times but somehow I wasn't able to find the correct answer that actually works. It is most likely due to my lack of experience/knowledge with the X.509 cert management, so I apologize in advance if I'm posting a duplicate.

Here's the deal. I've googled now for 3-4 days, tried various of things, even studied https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280 for a while, went over https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps documentation & related links, tried so many combinations but non seemed to work, and I'm pretty sure I'm missing some minor details that slipped through.

Essentially I have a very small TCP client/server app written in C# (.NET Framework 4.7). I strongly believe the server side is working properly, however, the client side seems to reject the certificate sent from the server upon validation. I will jump into the code.

Server side logic:

```
var pfxCert = new X509Certificate2(@"C:\...\Cert-EndUser.pfx", "password-2");
var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 20482);
listener.Start();
var client = await Listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync();
var sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), leaveInnerStreamOpen: false);
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer
(
    pfxCert,
    clientCertificateRequired: false,
    SslProtocols.Tls12,
    checkCertificateRevocation: true
);
```

Client side logic:

```
string serverName = @"www.my-domain.com";   // works, tested
string ip = "111.11.111.11";                // works, tested (obviously this is just dummy ip)

TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(ip), 20482);

SslStream sslStream = new SslStream
(
    client.GetStream(),
    leaveInnerStreamOpen: false,
    new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate),
    userCertificateSelectionCallback: null
);

try
{
    sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient
    (
        serverName,
        clientCertificates: null,
        SslProtocols.Tls12,
        checkCertificateRevocation: true
    );
}
catch (AuthenticationException e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show($"Exception: {e.Message}");
    client.Close();
    return;
}
```

Server cert validation function (for now):

```
public static bool ValidateServerCertificate
(
    object sender,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    X509Chain chain,
    SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors
)
{
    // sslPolicyErrors equals to SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors here
    if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Okay, as for the certificates, I'm just trying to make my own testing certificates just to have some base setup. Essentially, I am using windows powershell to make some (with New-SelfSignedCertificate command). Firstly I create a "root CA" certificate (let's call it "Cert-CA") which is self signed, then I create another certificate (called "Cert-EndUser" - the one im using in the server logic) which is signed by the Cert-CA. Then I install the Cert-CA certificate on the client side in the Trusted Root CA folder. I even tried to do it via code like this (although manual installation had no different behavior, and this code worked the same as if I would install it manually):

```
using (var cer = new X509Certificate2(@"Cert-CA.cer"))
using (var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
{
    store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
    store.Add(cer);
    store.Close();
}
```

So in a nutshell, Cert-CA is installed on the client machine, and Cert-EndUser is used in the communication (server uses it obviously), but Cert-EndUser is signed by Cert-CA, so that client side app can validate it. I can provide the powershell scripts I wrote which create both certificates:

Cert-CA creation (both .pfx + .cer):

```
### [S] EDITABLE SECTION ###

$Params = @{
    Type = "Custom"
    Provider = "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0"
    Subject = "C=..., ST=..., L=..., O=MyOrg, OU=OrgUnit, CN=MyOrg Trusted Root CA"
    DnsName = "www.my-domain.com"
    FriendlyName = "MyOrg-CA"
    HashAlgorithm = "SHA512"
    KeyAlgorithm = "RSA"
    KeyLength = 4096
    NotAfter = (Get-Date).AddYears(10)
    KeySpec = "Signature"
    KeyUsage = "CertSign","CRLSign","DigitalSignature"
    KeyUsageProperty = "Sign"
    TextExtension = @("2.5.29.19={critical}{text}cA=true")
    CertStoreLocation = "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"
}

$CertName = "Cert-CA"
$Password = "password-1"

### [E] EDITABLE SECTION ###

$CurrentDir = Get-Location
Set-Location Cert:\CurrentUser\My

$Cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate @Params
$CertLoc = "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$($Cert.Thumbprint)"

$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -Force -AsPlainText
$pfx = "$($CurrentDir)\$($CertName).pfx"
$cer = "$($CurrentDir)\$($CertName).cer"

Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $CertLoc -FilePath $pfx -Password $pwd
Export-Certificate -Cert $Cert -FilePath $cer
```

Cert-EndUser creation (both .pfx + .cer):

```
### [S] EDITABLE SECTION ###

$Params = @{
    Type = "SSLServerAuthentication","CodeSigningCert"
    Provider = "Microsoft Enhanced Cryptographic Provider v1.0"
    Subject = "C=.., ST=.., L=.., O=MyOrg, OU=Administration, CN=MyOrg Administration"
    DnsName = "www.my-domain.com"
    FriendlyName = "MyOrg"
    HashAlgorithm = "SHA512"
    KeyAlgorithm = "RSA"
    KeyLength = 4096
    NotAfter = (Get-Date).AddYears(2)
    KeySpec = "KeyExchange"
    KeyUsage = "DataEncipherment","DigitalSignature","KeyAgreement","KeyEncipherment"
    KeyUsageProperty = "KeyAgreement","Decrypt"
    TextExtension = @("2.5.29.19={text}cA=false", "2.5.29.37={text}1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.2,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.1,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.4,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3,1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.8")
    CertStoreLocation = "Cert:\CurrentUser\My"
}

$CertName = "Cert-EndUser"
$Password = "password-2" # the one also used in server logic

$SignerThumb = "THUMBPRINT_OF_CERT-CA"

### [E] EDITABLE SECTION ###

$CurrentDir = Get-Location
Set-Location Cert:\CurrentUser\My

$Params.Signer = Get-ChildItem -Path "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$($SignerThumb)"

$Cert = New-SelfSignedCertificate @Params
$CertLoc = "Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$($Cert.Thumbprint)"

$pwd = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $Password -Force -AsPlainText
$pfx = "$($CurrentDir)\$($CertName).pfx"
$cer = "$($CurrentDir)\$($CertName).cer"

Export-PfxCertificate -Cert $CertLoc -FilePath $pfx -Password $pwd
Export-Certificate -Cert $Cert -FilePath $cer
```

As I stated, server side seems to work properly, but on clinet side, validation fails (and I obviously don't want to use that "fix" where they just `return true` in `ValidateServerCertificate` callback and turn the security off, in that case I'd use plain old Sockets and be done with it).

What am I missing?

Comment: Inspect the X509Chain object in the callback.  Look at each ChainElement value and see what errors are attached at each level in the chain.

Comment: @bartonjs Wow, thanks! Idk why I did not check that but the error was in checking the revocation list.. Since I don't have any revocation list, when I set the "checkCertificateRevocation" flag to false, everything works! I guess I assumed if there is no revocation list, everything would work but seems like it does not. Thanks again!